# Keep asking the user to turn on the BT, until he does

Tags: android, android-studio, android-bluetooth, onactivityresult

In Android Studio: 
 
How can I ask the user to activate the BT and wait for a response later? 
My goal is to ask the user to turn on the BT, if he denies, show a Toast error and keep asking until he accepts 
 
I tried

```
private val REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 0
  ...
```

Then inside **onCreate**

```
val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()

if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth Device Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}

while (bluetoothAdapter?.isEnabled == false) {
      val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
      startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)
}
```

And outside i catched the intent:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED && requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "I need BT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

It does not give any compilation problems but it crashes the phone 
I guess because of the while loop 
There are probably better methods like **registerForActivityResult** but it still doesn't work

Comment: "it crashes the phone" -- use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with the crash.

Comment: I don't think it's relevant, startActivityForResult is asynchronous and calling it in a loop without a break sends the phone into overflow and chrashes

Comment: Your code does not appear to be calling it in a loop.